# Ionic find contacts

Tags: typescript, mobile, ionic2

I am trying to do a search in my Ionic 2 application on a phone number that has +1 in the front of it.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';
 import {Contacts, Contact, ContactField, ContactAddress, ContactName,ContactFindOptions} from '@ionic-native/contacts';
 import {ContactInterface} from "../../models/interfaces/contactInterface";

 /**
 * Generated class for the ContactMenuPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact-menu',
  templateUrl: 'contact-menu.html',
})
export class ContactMenuPage {

  contact : ContactInterface;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public navParams: NavParams,
              private callNumber: CallNumber,
              private contactCtrl: Contacts) {
      this.contact = this.navParams.get('contact');
      this.contact.exists = false;
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.contact.exists = false;
    console.log(this.contact.cell[0]);

    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
    options.filter = this.contact.cell[0];
    options.multiple = true;

    this.contactCtrl.find(['phoneNumbers'], options).then(
        (contacts) => {
            console.log(contacts);
        }
    );



  }
```

Whenever i do this it just gives me the first contact that was added to the contacts list. It must not give me anything if there are no matches.

Could you give me some pointers?

Comment: More context would help answer this. What is contactCtrl? does find return  Promise?

Comment: and magically as I post this query it works perfectly.

Comment: I will update it for future people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above uses the contact plugin for cordova and it returns an array of contact objects. I dont know why it wasnt working before but now its working perfectly so the above code is fine